# How can I store an R variable with the Rextension in Netlogo?

Tags: r, rstudio, netlogo

I am using the Rextension in Netlogo.

Using the function r:put, r:get and r:eval. I can use all of these, however, when I use r:put and later on run an entire code in R via r:eval, the value of r:put is not stored and thus the code of r:eval cannot run.

My Netlogo code:

```
to go
  r:clear
  r:put "x" 3
  print r:get "x" 
  r:eval "source('C:/Users/Amber van Oel/Documents/SEPAM/Thesis - ABM/Global 
  model/Netlogo oefenen/test2.r')"
end
```

My R code:

```
p <- 5 * x
```

The error I get when running this code is:

```
Extension exception: Error in R-Extension: Error in Eval: 
org.nlogo.api.ExtensionException: Error in eval(ei, envir) : object 'x' not 
found
```

The r:get "x" line is working, which means that the variable x is successfully transfered to R, however, I cannot use it in the second line.

Does anybody has experience with this error??

Comment: What happens if you do `r:eval "p <- x * 5"` and then `print r: get p` instead of the `r:eval` you have? Also, I don't think this is the problem, but I haven't had the R extension working since the change to NetLogo v6. Have you checked that all the R extension tests in the documentation still work?

Comment: I tried, but still not working..

Comment: What's still not working? Do you get the same error or a different one? Do the R extension tests work?